# Do app installs from the Apple Store automatically create a home screen shortcut icon?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play

Android OS 4.4+ automatically creates a home screen icon for Play Store installs by default, unless the user modifies their settings.

Do iPhones (OS 9+) also automatically create a home screen icon for Apple Store installs? Or is this a feature which needs to be included in the XCode for the iPhone app? I

Comment: what do you mean by "home screen"?

Comment: In iOS there is no separate home skin as there is no concept of menu. There are app folders and app icons and all are placed at the home screen.

Comment: Thank you. Are the app icons placed on the home screen automatically for all iPhone apps, or does this need to be coded into each app? Here is the Android equivalent: https://www.androidcentral.com/check-play-store-setting-you-do-anything-else

Comment: @RaceChasers: You dont need to code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all apps automatically place their icon on the home screen (there is no other place for them in iOS). If the first screen is full, it will be placed on a second screen which can be accessed by swiping left.

Comment: Both Turnipdabeets and BJHStudios responses were very helpful. I accepted the answer from BJHStudios as it answered the "automatic" question directly

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the [App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/). If this is the case, you need to provide those. It is not automatic.

In fact, you need to provide several different sizes depending on the devices you are to support.

> Every app must supply both small and large app icons. The small icons are used on the Home screen and throughout the system once your app is installed. The large icon is used by the App Store.

Check out [developer.apple.com/ios/](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/) for more details and spec.

If you have already provided the icons, you do not need to provide to functionality to show these App Icons on the Home screen.

Comment: he is not asking about the icon art, but whether the icon is placed on the screen. In Android there is a separate area for applications, so not all are placed on the home screen.

Comment: Thank you! This addresses my question directly "The small icons are used on the Home screen and throughout the system once your app is installed." I'm interpreting this to mean that they are added automatically upon download (as long as the app icons have been added to the Apple Store listing)

Comment: Glad to help @RaceChasers!